# Deploying on tomcat using maven

Tags: maven-2

i am deploying an application on apache-tomcat7 using maven but it gives dependency error, like this

```
com.moteve:moteve-server-core:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.moteve -DartifactId=moteve-server-c
ore -Dversion=0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
```

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.moteve -DartifactId=moteve-server-cor
e -Dversion=0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -Drepo
sitoryId=[id]



 Path to dependency:
   1) com.moteve:moteve-server-webapp:war:0.1-SNAPSHOT
   2) com.moteve:moteve-server-core:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

---

1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact:

```
 com.moteve:moteve-server-webapp:war:0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

here is my pom.xml file

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    enter code here




  <parent>
    <groupId>com.moteve</groupId>![enter image description here][1]
    <artifactId>moteve-server-parent</artifactId>
    <version>${moteve-server-parent-version}</version>
    <relativePath>../moteve-server-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.moteve</groupId>
  <artifactId>moteve-server-webapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>${moteve-server-webapp-version}</version>
  <name>Moteve Web Application</name>
  <url>http://moteve.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.moteve</groupId>
      <artifactId>moteve-server-core</artifactId>
      <version>${moteve-server-core-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>${servlet-api-version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-webmvc-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>moteve-server-webapp</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add deploy dependency in maven and try to run 
mvn clean install